# Customize styling in date picker ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I want to add custom styles in the date picker of ngx-bootstrap (in angular 4) since I want the header of date picker to have white background and all the text that is present on the header like month name, arrow keys, year of black color.

The default styling in bs-datepicker.css does not provide the required styling. Is there any alternative to modify the default styling other than modifying library files because its not an option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just overwrite standard styles in your project's stylesheet, but you'll need to use more specific selectors or `!important`.

```
body .bs-datepicker-container .bs-datepicker-head {
  background-color: #fff;
}
body .bs-datepicker-container .bs-datepicker-head * {
  color: #000;
}
```

Example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z9cn3d?file=styles.css

Comment: This worked for me when adding it to styles.css but wouldn't work if this was added to the css file of the specific component

Answer (score 0):

Change the color variable

```
.bs-datepicker-head,
.bs-datepicker-head, .bs-datepicker button:active,
.bs-datepicker-body table td span.selected, 
.bs-datepicker-body table td.selected span,
.bs-datepicker-body table td span[class*="select-"]:after,
.bs-datepicker-body table td[class*="select-"] span:after, 
.bs-datepicker-body table td.active-week span:hover 
{
background-color: $primary !important; 
}

.bs-datepicker-body table td.week span 
{
color: $primary !important; 
}
```